# Switch: возможно ли по ошибке написать два одинаковых case'а?

Tags: алгоритм, дизайн-языка

На Хабрахабре, в комментариях к [статье](https://habr.com/ru/post/320712/) о Switch, было такое:

> У if-else есть один большой недостаток: ошибка копипасты. В switch невозможно по ошибке написать два одинаковых case, в if-else это случается постоянно.

Что имел в виду автор?

На мой взгляд, ошибиться вполне себе можно. Например, написать два раза `bar` вместо `bar` и `baz`. Разве нет?

```
Switch Var {
    Case "foo", "bar", "baz":
        // do something
    Default:
        // do something else
}
```

Я бы спросил у автора. Создал аккаунт на Хабре, но сайт пишет, что я не могу комментировать записи старше 30 дней.

Comment: Ну, в С/С++ вы действительно не сможете это сделать. Вернее, написать-то сможете, но вот работать (компилироваться) это не станет..

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я привык работать с другим языком, значительно менее строгим, и про С/С++ как-то не подумал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нельзя на Си и Си++:
https://ideone.com/htMInL

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
  volatile int x = 1;
 
  switch (x)
  {
    case 1:   break;
    case 1:   break;
  }
 
  return 0;
}
```

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:12:5: error: duplicate case value
     case 1:   break;
     ^~~~
prog.cpp:11:5: note: previously used here
     case 1:   break;
     ^~~~
```

Нельзя на C#:
https://ideone.com/Yx4zhb

```
using System;
 
public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    int x = 1;
 
    switch (x)
    {
      case 1:   break;
      case 1:   break;
    }
  }
}
```

```
prog.cs(12,7): error CS0152: The label `case 1:' already occurs in this switch statement
prog.cs(11,7): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Нельзя на Джаве:
https://ideone.com/sLL76R

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    int x = 1;
    
    switch (x) {
      case 1:   break;
      case 1:   break;
    }
  }
}
```

```
Main.java:7: error: duplicate case label
      case 1:   break;
      ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибиться можно. Но

```
if (x==bar)
{
}
else
{
 if (x==bar)
 {
 }
}
```

вместо

```
if (x==bar)
{
}
else
{
 if (x==baz)
 {
 }
}
```

компилируется, а

```
switch (x)
{
 case bar:
 break;
 case bar:
 break;
}
```

вместо

```
switch (x)
{
 case bar:
 break;
 case baz:
 break;
}
```

– нет.